# how to iterate a list variable in html using razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to asp .net and MVC. I have a service method called Jumbo(). This method returns a list containing first name, last name and contact number. And I call this method from my main project as below. Also I return it to the view page.

```
var info = add.jumbo();
ViewData["sample"] = info;

return View("FormResults");
```

When I debugged the code the variable 'info' contains all the data I needed. The problem is how do I iterate the variable in html table using razor. I searched a lot to find a solution but I failed. Please help me with a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case 1:**
Basically you can observe this within your application itself. MVC itself provide you your answer. When ? When you creating View against the action which returning list. Say your action returning list of customer then you can observe following code.

```
@model IEnumerable<Customer>

<h2>Customers</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateCustomer", "ControllerName")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {    
        <tr>           
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>

                <td>                        

                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit |", "UpdateCustomer", new { id =  item.Id}) 
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id =  item.Id}) 
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id =  item.Id})                      
               </td>           
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**Case 2:** 
your scenario is when you sending the list within ViewData. Then you have to cast ViewData into respective model list and then you can perform same foreach loop.
Action:
    var info = add.jumbo();
    ViewData["sample"] = info;

```
return View("FormResults");
```

View:

```
  @if (ViewData["sample"] != null)
    {
        List<Info> infoList = (List<Info>)ViewData["sample"];
        foreach (var i in infoList)
        { 
        //Perform your html here enclosed with html tags.
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

First you need to pass the model to the view:

```
return View("FormResults", info);
```

And in the view, you'll need to state the Type of model, and use @ to indicate code rather than html:

```
@model List<Foo> // Whatever your list is
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <span>@item.Text</span>
}
```

Here's a blog about it in detail: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor

Comment: I don't use Model. I call the service from my controller and store it in a variable. Also I pass my data to the view. I have a separate project for my services. Actually I am not sure whether I am doing it correctly. Please help me

Comment: Consider I have my service method Jumbo() in project1 and I call that method from project2. I have a list named UserTable in project1. I retrieve data from db and store it in that list(project1). From my project2 I jsut call that method and store it to a variable. How can I include that list to my View in project2? Please help me...

Comment: @user3627446 if `UserTable` is the class name, then change `Foo` from this answer to `UserTable` and change `item.Text` to the correct property name, i.e `item.FirstName`.

Comment: I tried replacing Foo with List<userTable> but it show error 'Only assignment,call, increment,decrement,await and new object expressions can be used as a statement'

Answer (score 3):

```
@model  Models.Nodes 
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 <li>
    <span> item.name </span>
 </li>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your view  write a foreach loop as below

```
@model List<Object>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  item.YourProperty;//without html
  <label>@item.YourProperty</label> //in html
}
```